# Laravel 5 routes ( couple non-required parameters)

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

I need to make functionality, when action has **two non-required parameters**.

So action could be called like this:

```
site/man/process/age/30/weight/80, 

site/man/process/age/30,

site/man/process/weight/80,

site/man/process/
```

I am trying to use route like this:

```
Route::get('man/process/age/{age?}/weight/{weight?}', 'ManController@process');
```

But have no success. Anybody knows how to do this correctly?

Thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: I think you should make your params as a query string and not something like that.
so you'd have something like..
`/man/process?age=10&weight=20`

Comment: I think you should investigate making multiple routes. Highest being the route you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('man/process', 'ManController@process');
URL : /man/process?age=10&weight=20
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take an entirely different approach to passing these variables via route parameters.

Consider sending a POST request with age and weight in the body of the request, then accessing these values in your controller with $request->all();

edit with example:

`Route::post('man/process', 'ManController@process');`

Then in your controller process() method:

```
process(Request $request)
{
  // Data in this case would contain age and weight
  $data = $request->all();
}
```

Comment: I would even go as far to use a `GET` request e.g. `man/process?age=31&weight=80`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GET` request, And pass the parameters as query string.

```
Route::get('man/process', 'ManController@process');
URL : /man/process?age=10&weight=20
```

Or use `POST` Request and pass along the stuff you want to receive:

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
  // Data in this case would contain age and weight
  $data = $request->all();
}
```